Getting Error while http request between spring boot and react project
I have an API which coded by Spring Boot framework and make http requests to the API with reactJs.
requests comes from a different computer to my computer but they connected in same wifi connection.
then I got multiple error in the both side
in reactJs side:
HTTP_PROTOCOL_ERROR
in spring boot side:
`Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x060xc00x010x000x060xbc0x030x030x83/0x820x0b0xc70x9b)0x0b0xbe0x100xb20xe9<0x15Ty0xde0x850xfb0xf40xe50x9f0x8e'0x0e0x150xce0xf90xf0v"0xb8 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]`
https://myIPV4Adress:8082/arac/create/1
Other computer tried a request but returned the error as i mentioned about it.
